# How to Union Two Tables and Overwrite Preexisting Rows

Tags: sql-server, join, union

I want to combine two tables into one,
but if in table 1 the account code "Acc1" is the same as in table 2 the account code "Acc1"
then I want to take the amount in table 1 as the result

**Table 1

Account Code    AccountName Project Type    Desc    Period  Amount**

Bcc1    AccountBone AA  Good    PC2000  11/30/2022  700

Acc1    AccountOne  AA  Good    PC2000  12/1/2022   300

**Table 2

Account Code    AccountName Project Type    Desc    Period  Amount**

Acc1    AccountOne  AA  Good    PC2000  12/1/2022   220

Acc2    AccountOne  AA  Good    PC2000  12/2/2022   432

**Result

Account Code    AccountName Project Type    Desc    Period  Amount**

Bcc1    AccountBone AA  Good    PC2000  11/30/2022  700

Acc1    AccountOne  AA  Good    PC2000  12/1/2022   300

Acc2    AccountOne  AA  Good    PC2000  12/2/2022   432

I was expecting a query for this case

Comment: *"I was expecting a query for this case"* what do you mean by this? What were you using to expect it to give you a query? What is your question here exactly? What is the difficulty you are having achyyoit goal(s)?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be a full outer join and an unpivoting technique to select the columns from `T1` if there was a match or `T2` otherwise ([DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DFMn2Xt3))

```
SELECT CA.*
FROM   Table1 t1
       FULL JOIN Table2 t2
              ON t1.AccountCode = t2.AccountCode
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT t1.AccountCode,
                           t1.AccountName /*and other columns*/
                    WHERE  t1.AccountCode IS NOT NULL
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT t2.AccountCode,
                           t2.AccountName /*and other columns*/
                    WHERE  t1.AccountCode IS NULL) CA
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit confusing. However, based on your results wouldn't this just work:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempTable1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempTable2;

CREATE TABLE #TempTable1
(
    AccountCode VARCHAR(100),
    AccountName VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE #TempTable2
(
    AccountCode VARCHAR(100),
    AccountName VARCHAR(100)
);

GO

INSERT INTO #TempTable1(AccountCode, AccountName)
VALUES('Bcc1', 'AccountBone'),
('Acc1', 'AccountOne');

INSERT INTO #TempTable2(AccountCode, AccountName)
VALUES('Acc1', 'AccountOne'),
('Acc2', 'AccountOne');

SELECT *
FROM #TempTable1
UNION
SELECT *
FROM #TempTable2;
```

Comment: `UNION` without `ALL` creates a set with distinct rows. In your example you only have AccountCode and AccountName, while Arif had also Project, Type, Desc, Period and Amount columns which were not the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could select all from Table1 and from Table2 select all that do not exist in Table1:

```
select * 
from Table1
union
select * 
from Table2
where AccountCode not in (
  select AccountCode
  from Table1
)
```

See a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yVYUaVdA)